# How to add values to only certain index in Numpy 2D Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a 2d Matrix

```
matrix = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
index = np.array([0, 1, 1])
add_value = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

I want to add add_value to matrix but only to the elements corresponding to index in the index list. For example, 1 in add_value should be added to the first element in [1,2], which is 1, resulting in 2.
So the output should be

```
np.array([[2,2],[3,6],[5,9]])
```

Comment: `matrix[np.r_[:matrix.shape[0]], index] += add_value`?

Comment: you are a genius. have a lovely day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple multi-dimensional indexing:

```
matrix[np.arange(matrix.shape[0]), index] += add_value
```

Or using python builtins:

```
matrix[tuple(zip(*enumerate(index)))] += add_value
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [5, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, x in enumerate(add_value):
    matrix[i][index[i]] += x
```

Comment: This will be slow on large arrays

Comment: Good to know thanks. For me it's the easiest way to understand what's happening.